# How to install WIjesekara Sinhala keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way to install SInhala unicode(Wijesekara layout) in the latest distribution ? I'm a total newbie, so it will be a great help if you can explain it ;)

Comment: Latest distribution of what?  (*please clarify*)

Comment: Sinhala is the main language of Sri Lanka. There are 60 letters but it can be adapted to a standard keyboard. Have a look here, not sure if it works with 20.04: https://www.ubuntu4u.com/howtos/how-type-sinhala-ubuntu-1204-lts

Answer (score 0):

### Sinhala Keyboard Ubuntu 20.04

- Select **Show Applications** icon, (Lower Left corner).
- Select **Language Support**.
- Complete **Install of Language Support**.
- Select **Install/Remove Languages**. Check the box next to **Sinhala**.
- In **Regional Format** select **Sinhala**
- Open **Settings** / **Language and Region**.
- Click **+** sign.
- Type `sinhala` at bottom of **Add an Input Source**, if not already shown.
- Select **Sinhala (Wijesekara)**.
- Check **Add** upper right.

If you are also keeping the US keyboard select your current preference using the icon upper right next to the WiFi icon.

Comment: any clue for 22.04?